# How to Translate Power Metrics in Raven Pro to Received Levels

Tags: pam, calibration, raven, received-level

I added in-band power and average power measurements to my selection table in Raven. I also have the end to end calculation of my instruments. To calculate the received levels, is it just a matter of adding the values together?

I know Raven has a calibration option, but I cannot edit or add anything to it. Given my calibration is straight forward, being end-to-end, can I just easily calculate it myself?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with processing data uncalibrated, i.e. using ADC values, and to add calibration at the end, i.e. when presenting the result.

You only have to avoid (or take into acount) any rescaling of the data by the signal processing package you are using. There is no signal processing standard and, IIRC, there are some packages that rescale data when no calibration is given.